# Select all zeros xor all values > zero in one statement

Tags: postgresql, grafana, echarts

I need to deal with following question:

We talk about monitoring a small photovoltaic plant.

```
table.column1 = timestamp
table.column2 = double precision
```

In the mentioned table there are values of the output power that are zero (no sun or even snow) and values that are > zero.

my current query is as following:

```
select
  date_trunc('m', column1),
  avg(column2)
from table
where date(column1) = date(current_timestamp) and column2 > 0
group by date_trunc('m', column1)
order by date_trunc('m', column2);
```

This works fine as long as the power plant is working. At night or with snow on the modules, of course the measured values are zeros and going not be selected by this statement.

Now, I need a way to select all values > zero (as above) or, select the zeros if all values until now are zero.

Comment: I don't understand what your goal is, or what the problem with the current query is. If you want to include the zero values, remove the condition?

Comment: As I wrote: All values > zeros or even the zeros if until now are only zeros in the result. If there are only zeros, the result is null. Grafana with echarts plugin can't deal with null values so it shown an error messages. But I will only visualize zeros if the whole day contains zeros. Otherwise I will only visualize values > zero and I will not visualize a mix of zeros and values > zero

Comment: Sounds like this would better be solved in grafana or the chart itself, but if you have to do it in sql, `and (column2 > 0 or not exists(select * from table where date(column1) = date(column1) and column2 > 0))` should do

Comment: Cool. It shows the values of today correctly. I'll check tomorrow morning. Before sunrise, I expect to see the zero line

Comment: I made a small adjustment but now it seems to work: ```and (column2 > 0 or not exists(select * from table where date(column1) = date(current_timestamp) and column2 > 0))```

Comment: Oh yeah that's what I meant